# Difference between "atom swap!" and "ref commute"

Tags: clojure

What's the difference between?

1.

```
(def x (ref 0))
(dosync
  (commute x f))
```

2.

```
(def x (atom 0))
(swap! x f))
```

These two examples work equally

Comment: The premise of this question is false,`commute` will throw an exception when called on an atom. Perhaps you wanted to know the difference between `alter` and `commute`? If so that is answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999281/ref-set-vs-commute-vs-alter

Comment: If you are wondering about the differences between vars, refs, atoms, and agents, I recommend [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9136699/2472391). If you are wondering about the ways to change a ref, I recommend [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4999888/2472391). If you are wondering about atoms, I recommend [this link](http://clojure.org/atoms), and then rephrasing your question.

Comment: @noisesmith sorry, ref in first example

Comment: Hope this topic is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132346/clojure-differences-between-ref-var-agent-atom-with-examples/9136699#9136699

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have only one ref and one atom, there actually is no big difference. I think you might learn something about the difference of atoms and refs.

`commute` is a function which can be called in any place in the `dosync` block. Clojure itself chooses when to execute an `commute` inside this block.

Maybe I explan it with a small example:

```
(def x (ref 0))
(def y (ref 0))
(dosync (alter x inc)
        (alter y dec))
```

`alter` changes the value of a ref inside a `dosync` block. Because refs are coordinated and synchronous, we need to place them inside this block. If here occurs an error while altering one of the refs, the whole block fails and your refs have the same value as they had before calling the alters.

The difference to commute is the following: If we have the following code block

```
(def x (ref 0))
(def y (ref 0))
(dosync (commute x inc)
        (alter y dec))
```

If an error occurs here while changing the value of your refs, `commute` is still called and it changes your ref. It does not care about the result of the `alter` and even if the `alter` fails, `commute` does increment x.
Clojure can choose when to call commute, so it can be executed even if an error occurs.

The big difference to atoms is that atoms are not coordinated. If there are multiple `swap!` on one atom, maybe just the first `swap!` will be executed. One of my projects got stuck on this issue, I had to ensure that the first `swap!` has terminated before the next `swap!` is called.

So again: **Think of what you really need**. Do you need an atom or some refs? If you choose refs, you have the choice between `alter`, which is executed at the position you want it to, or `commute` where Clojure can decide when to call it (the call is then *commutative*).

If you choose an atom, you can only change one value while this atom is executed. If another call trys to `swap!` the value, it is rejected.