# Clojure commute and alter performance

Tags: clojure, stm

There is a little bit modified example from [clojure.org/refs](http://clojure.org/)

```
(defn mod-nth [v i f] (assoc v i (f (v i))))
(defn run [oper nvecs nitems nthreads niters]
  (let [vec-refs (vec (map (comp ref vec)
                        (partition nitems (repeat (* nvecs nitems) 0))))
        sum  #(reduce + %)
        swap #(let [v1 (rand-int nvecs)
                    v2 (rand-int nvecs)
                    i1 (rand-int nitems)
                    i2 (rand-int nitems)]
                (dosync
                  (let [temp (nth @(vec-refs v1) i1)]
                    (oper (vec-refs v1) mod-nth i1 inc)
                    (oper (vec-refs v2) mod-nth i2 dec))))
        report #(do
                  (prn (map deref vec-refs))
                  (println "Sum:"
                    (reduce + (map (comp sum deref) vec-refs))))]
    (report)
    (dorun (apply pcalls (repeat nthreads #(dotimes [_ niters] (swap)))))
    (report)))

(time (run alter 100 10 10 100000))
```

sample output is

```
([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [...])
Sum: 0
([15 -14 -8 57 -26 -12 -49 -29 33 -3] [...])
Sum: 0
"Elapsed time: 1995.938147 msecs"
```

Instead of swapping unique numbers i'm transferring ones from one vector elements to another.

This operation could be assumed as commutative so there is another test - it's the same except `commute` is used instead of `alter`

```
(time (run commute 100 10 10 100000))
```

with sample output like

```
([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [...])
Sum: 0
([8 48 -10 -41 -17 -32 -4 50 -31 88] [...])
Sum: 0
"Elapsed time: 3141.591517 msecs"
```

Surprisingly first example is running in about `2 seconds` while second needs `3 seconds`

But as mentioned [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999888/210905)

> `commute` is an optimized version of alter for those times when the order of things really does not matter

How it could be optimized while it needs more time to do the same work in this simple case?
What is the purpose of `commute` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to monitor the `clojure.core` functions involved when running the example using both `alter` and `commute`.

## `alter`

[image: alter]

## `commute`

[image: commute]

**If my interpretation of the results are correct**, the accumulated time spent on each function shows that `commute` is actually faster than `alter`. It seems the overhead of all the other operations that need to be done to run the code in parallel are the ones that mess up the performance.

Benchmarking code is quite tricky and using `time` is sometimes misleading. The information provided by VisualVm might not even be the ultimate word though, profiling and using tools such as [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) might be the best way to make sure results are trustworthy.

Another important fact is that the operations done inside the `dosync` block don't take that long, so even if one of them retries, the extra time this involves is not that significant. Adding a slight delay inside the `dosync` makes the difference between retrying (`alter`) and not retrying (`commute`) be more noticeable.

```
(defn mod-nth [v i f] (assoc v i (f (v i))))
(defn run [oper nvecs nitems nthreads niters]
  (let [vec-refs (vec (map (comp ref vec)
                        (partition nitems (repeat (* nvecs nitems) 0))))
        sum  #(reduce + %)
        swap #(let [v1 (rand-int nvecs)
                    v2 (rand-int nvecs)
                    i1 (rand-int nitems)
                    i2 (rand-int nitems)]
               (dosync
                 (let [temp (nth @(vec-refs v1) i1)]
                   (Thread/sleep 1)                     ;; This was added
                   (oper (vec-refs v1) mod-nth i1 inc)
                   (oper (vec-refs v2) mod-nth i2 dec))))
        report #(do
                  (prn (map deref vec-refs))
                  (println "Sum:"
                    (reduce + (map (comp sum deref) vec-refs))))]
    (doall (apply pcalls (repeat nthreads #(dotimes [_ niters] 
                                            (swap)))))))

(time (run alter 100 10 10 5000))
;= "Elapsed time: 15252.427 msecs"
(time (run commute 100 10 10 5000))
;= "Elapsed time: 13595.399 msecs"
```

Comment: So question is: Shouldn't i use `alter` over `commute` when transaction operations are tiny?

Comment: That is a good question. I wouldn't dare to generalise though, the best way that I know to figure out this kind of stuff, is trying things and measuring the results. If it were me I would choose according to the nature of the operations performed (commutative and not commutative) and only then if it turns out to be a bottleneck, try with the other one.

Comment: @Odomontois, the other thing to keep in mind is that the Clojure implementation can optimize the `commute` case in the future. You're giving it more information about your code to do something with, so it's _able_ to be more efficient, whether it _actually is_ more efficient at any given point release (for any given code block) or not. Writing your code based on implementation-specific benchmarks may help you when running against one release, but if you aren't re-benchmarking whenever a new Clojure runtime comes out...

Answer (score 3):

It's important to understand what the optimization made by `commute` is specifically: *`commute` avoids unnecessarily rerunning the code inside your block in situations where `alter` would need to throw away results.*

Constant-factor overhead between the implementations of `commute` and `alter` is not specified, so what you're seeing here violates no part of the Clojure specification. That said -- as the amount of time spent by individual transactions inside your `dosync` block grows, the penalty for using `alter` when you could instead use `commute` will grow similarly.

In general:

- Microbenchmarks are evil (in the sense that they encourage bad practices that don't scale to real-world use). Pay attention to performance behavior in real-world scenarios, not contrived test cases.
- Use `commute` in Clojure's STM whenever you can.